# How to set text in Pages with applescript

Tags: applescript

Is there any way to set text from applescript in macos 12.4?  I get an
`Error:  Can’t set every text of \"The\" to \"hello\".-10006""`
with the script below, when I run having a test document up in pages.

```
tell application "Pages"
    set mydoc to first document
    
    try
        set t to "hello"
        set b to body text of mydoc
        set p to first paragraph of b
        set w to first word of p                
        set text of w to t
    on error errMsg number errorNumber
        display dialog "Error:  " & errMsg & errorNumber as text
    end try
    
end tell
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the AppleScript dictionary of Pages.app or [this article](https://iworkautomation.com/pages/)

Comment: Thanks Vadian!  After looking at the iworkautomation.com page, I see how to edit a text box (set object text) and it looks like I can change the entire document (set body text) but is there a way to change a single word within the body?  The pages dictionary talks about a placeholderText object, but it looks like that is more for templates.

Comment: I see it now!!! 'set (last word of first paragraph of body text of mydoc) to t'